# How to query for a null fields with graphql?

Tags: javascript, graphql, graphql-js

I'm trying to query for a field that **can** be `null` or its `_gt`, but cannot find a way to make this work.

I've tried this:

```
  query GetBanner {
    foo(
      sort: "posicao:asc", 
      where: { 
        startDate_lt: "2021-10-13T21:13:16.510Z", 
        _or: [
          { endDate_gt: "2021-10-13T21:13:16.510Z"},
          { endDate: null }
        ]
      }
    ) {
      id
      created_at
      updated_at
      startDate
      endDate
    }
  }
```

But I'm getting the following error message:
`Invalid format, expected a timestamp or an ISO date`

How to properly query this?

Comment: just don't pass it, leave it undedfined (equals to null)

Comment: But I don't receive the null values with only the `endDate_gt` and I need to specify that I want both, documents that now is before `endDate` or `endDate` is null

Comment: it all depends on backend implementation, types defined, resolver accepting/interpreting values ... adapt it to accept null?

Comment: Hmm I didn't know this, I'll try it